# Or in XPath expression to select from multiple node names

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

Given XML like this...

```
<Rule scope="node">
    <Property>regKeyExists</Property>
    <Path>HKLM\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\ K:@microsoft.com/GENUINE</Path>                             
    <Operator>-eq</Operator>
    <Value>true</Value>
</Rule>
<Or scope="node">
    <Rule>
        <Property>regKeyExists</Property>
        <Path>HKLM\SOFTWARE\MozillaPlugins\ K:@microsoft.com/GENUINE</Path>                             
        <Operator>-eq</Operator>
        <Value>true</Value>
    </Rule>
</Or>
```

...but which could have nodes other than `<Rule>` and `<Or>`, and could have values for `Scope` other than "node", I am trying to select just the Rule and Or nodes where scope=node.
Currently I am using `$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("./*[@scope='node']")` then looping with `foreach ($node in $nodes)` and checking `$node.name` so I can work with just the Rule and Or nodes. But my preference would be to do it with XPath. I have found reference to using `or` in predicate expressions, but only with attributes, not with node names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//*[self::Rule or self::Or][@scope='node']
```

will select all `Rule` or `Or` elements with `@scope` attribute values of `'node'`.

Comment: Oh, THAT is not an approach I would have grokked on my own. Cool. Learned something on a Friday!

Answer (score 1):

XPath 2.0 allows

```
//(Rule|Or)[@scope='node']
```

and XPath 1.0 gets close with

```
(//Rule|//Or)[@scope='node']
```